# Adding ROW_NUMBER() to query loses DISTINCT, defeats the purpose of paged results attempt

Tags: sql, distinct, one-to-many, row-number, delimited

I'm having a problem bringing back a truly `DISTINCT` set of records using `ROW_NUMBER()` with a `LEFT JOIN` whose joined results are in turn concatenated into a comma-delimited list with the `FOR XML PATH` trick.

The objective is to implement paging in a web application because of the large number of records that can be returned and *only bringing back a subset* each time depending on what page number was selected.

Consider the following SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT IndustryCode, 
STUFF ( 
    (SELECT ',' + FE_LocationCode
    FROM tblLegacy_Codes i2
    WHERE c.IndustryCode = i2.IndustryCode
    FOR XML PATH(''))
,1,1,'') AS LegacyList
FROM Common_Clli c
LEFT JOIN tblLegacy_Codes legacy ON c.IndustryCode = legacy.IndustryCode
WHERE FE_LocationCode LIKE 'AUS%'
```

It brings back a very nice `DISTINCT` list as expected:

```
IndustryCode    LegacyList
AUSTTX85        AUST.GET,AUST.LDD,AUST.UU4
AUSTTXTE        AUST.TE,AUST.TEH
AUSUTX78        AUST.AX3
SCHWAS01        AUSC01C1,AUSC01UT
SZBGASAH        AUSB01C1,AUSB01OB,AUSB01TA
SZBGASAI        AUSB01SN,AUVI01SN,AUVI02SN
SZBGASAK        AUSB03C1,AUSB03V1
```

BUT - when the ROW_NUMBER syntax is added to the first line of the query above so that it looks like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IndustryCode) AS rowNum, IndustryCode,...
```

The results now include a row for each IndustryCode for as many are in the LegacyList because `DISTINCT` of course now includes rowNum. Without including the entire result set, here is what is seen just for the first IndustryCode in the list because of its 3 associated child records:

```
rowNum  IndustryCode    LegacyList
1       AUSTTX85        AUST.GET,AUST.LDD,AUST.UU4
2       AUSTTX85        AUST.GET,AUST.LDD,AUST.UU4
3       AUSTTX85        AUST.GET,AUST.LDD,AUST.UU4
```

And of course the final implementation of paging is to be able to wrap all the SQL mentioned *with*

```
SELECT * FROM (
  [ the SQL you've already seen ]
WHERE rowNum BETWEEN x and y
```

For the moment I've had to resort to executing the SQL first without ROW_NUMBER() and putting the results into a temp table and then getting the final product from there. And unfortunately that has totally defeated the intention of minimizing load by only getting a subset of records every time.

I'm fairly convinced there's just something I don't know. It's always a safe bet. Many regards for help.

**The final product that satisfies *all* the requirements ends up being the SQL below.** While both the first 2 solutions offered were helpful, neither addressed the need to NOT house the entire results of the query first in a temporary style table, whether that table be a common table expression or something else. This [StackOverflow thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2390142/in-sql-server-how-can-i-use-row-number-with-a-subquery-column) led me to a complete resolution.

```
SELECT RowNum, IndustryCode, FEList FROM
(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IndustryCode) AS RowNum, IndustryCode, FEList
    FROM
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT IndustryCode,
        STUFF (
            (SELECT ',' + FE_LocationCode
            FROM tblLegacyCodes i2
            WHERE c.IndustryCode = i2.IndustryCode
            FOR XML PATH(''))
        ,1,1,'') AS LegacyList
        FROM Common_Clli c
        LEFT JOIN tblLegacyCodes legacy ON c.IndustryCode = legacy.IndustryCode
        WHERE FE_LocationCode LIKE 'AUS%'
    ) subInner
) subOuter
WHERE RowNum BETWEEN x AND y
```

Comment: row_number() is unique (1..N), so that's what distinct does.

Comment: Move your select distinct to a subquery, then select from that with the row number.

Answer (score 3):

What about

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IndustryCode) AS rowNum, IndustryCode, LegacyList
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT IndustryCode, 
STUFF ( 
    (SELECT ',' + FE_LocationCode
    FROM tblLegacy_Codes i2
    WHERE c.IndustryCode = i2.IndustryCode
    FOR XML PATH(''))
,1,1,'') AS LegacyList
FROM Common_Clli c
LEFT JOIN tblLegacy_Codes legacy ON c.IndustryCode = legacy.IndustryCode
WHERE FE_LocationCode LIKE 'AUS%'
) T
ORDER BY rowNum
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use table expressions, like

```
WITH MYTABLE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT IndustryCode, 
STUFF ( 
    (SELECT ',' + FE_LocationCode
    FROM tblLegacy_Codes i2
    WHERE c.IndustryCode = i2.IndustryCode
    FOR XML PATH(''))
,1,1,'') AS LegacyList
FROM Common_Clli c
LEFT JOIN tblLegacy_Codes legacy ON c.IndustryCode = legacy.IndustryCode
WHERE FE_LocationCode LIKE 'AUS%'
) SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY IndustryCode) AS ROWNUM
, IndustryCode, LegacyList FROM MYTABLE
```

Answer (score -1):

An exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code

has too many arguments specified.

Error solved in Arguments

```
@productCodeId varchar(15),
@productName varchar(60), 
@categoryCodeId varchar(15),
@subCategoryCodeId varchar(15),
@childSubCategoryCodeId varchar(15),
@productKeyword varchar(max),
@productCode varchar(25),
@productImage image=null,
@productDescShort varchar(max),
@ProductDescFull varchar(max),
@qualityProcessCertification varchar(max),
@userCodeId varchar(15),

 @productInfoCodeId varchar(15),
@productAdvantage varchar(max),
@productPriceInformation varchar(25),
@productAddPrice decimal(10,0),
@sampleAvailability varchar(5),
@deliveryLeadTime varchar(50),
@deliveryTerm varchar(max),
@minQuantity varchar(25),
@status varchar(15),


@id varchar(15)=null output ,
@id1 varchar(15)=null output
```

AS
   BEGIN

--declare @id varchar(15)=null
--declare @id1 varchar(15)=null

select @id=tp.productCodeId, @id1=tpi.productCodeId from tbl_product as tp
   inner join tbl_ProductInformation as tpi
   on tp.productCodeId= tpi.productCodeId
   where tp.productCodeId=@productCodeId and tpi.productCodeId=@productCodeId

```
if @id=@productCodeId and @id1=@productCodeId
```

begin
    update tbl_product set
    productName=@productName,categoryCodeId=@categoryCodeId,
    subCategoryCodeId=@subCategoryCodeId,childSubCategoryCodeId=@childSubCategoryCodeId,
    productKeyword=@productKeyword,productCode=@productCode, productImage=@productImage,
    productDescShort=@productDescShort,
    ProductDescFull=@ProductDescFull,qualityProcessCertification=@qualityProcessCertification,
    userCodeId=@userCodeId
    FROM tbl_product tp, tbl_ProductInformation tpi
    where tp.productCodeId= @productCodeId and tpi.productCodeId=@productCodeId

```
update tbl_ProductInformation set productInfoCodeId=@productInfoCodeId, productAdvantage=@productAdvantage,
productPriceInformation=@productPriceInformation,
productAddPrice=@productAddPrice,sampleAvailability=@sampleAvailability,deliveryLeadTime=@deliveryLeadTime,
deliveryTerm=@deliveryTerm,minQuantity=@minQuantity,productCodeId=@productCodeId
FROM tbl_product tp, tbl_ProductInformation tpi
```

where tp.productCodeId=@productCodeId and tpi.productCodeId=@productCodeId
 end
    else
begin
    insert into tbl_product(productCodeId,productName,categoryCodeId,
    subCategoryCodeId,childSubCategoryCodeId,productKeyword,productCode,productImage,productDescShort,
    ProductDescFull,qualityProcessCertification,userCodeId)
    values(@productCodeId,@productName,@categoryCodeId,
    @subCategoryCodeId,@childSubCategoryCodeId,@productKeyword,@productCode,@productImage,@productDescShort,
    @ProductDescFull,@qualityProcessCertification,@userCodeId)

```
insert into tbl_ProductInformation(productInfoCodeId,productAdvantage,
productPriceInformation,productAddPrice,sampleAvailability,deliveryLeadTime,deliveryTerm,minQuantity,productCodeId,status)
values(@productInfoCodeId,@productAdvantage,@productPriceInformation,@productAddPrice,
@sampleAvailability,@deliveryLeadTime,@deliveryTerm,@minQuantity,@productCodeId,@status)
```

end